# Why is my local font not being applied with Emotion global styling?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face, emotion, css-in-js

I am trying to use a locally hosted font in a React project that utilizes Emotion, and its [Global component](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals). This method works great for web fonts, like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), but when I downloaded that same font and tried to apply it as a local `.ttf` file using `@font-face`, I couldn't achieve the same result.

Here's the important file, **`App.js`**:

```
import React from "react";

import { Global, css } from "@emotion/core";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const GlobalStyles = css`
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap");

  @font-face {
    font-family: "Local Font";
    src: url("fonts/DancingScript-Regular.ttf");
  }

  * {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

const FromGoogle = styled.h1`
  font-family: "Dancing Script";
`;

const FromLocal = styled.h1`
  font-family: "Local Font";
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Global styles={GlobalStyles} />
      <FromGoogle>This text's font family is from Google.</FromGoogle>
      <FromLocal>
        This text's font family should be the same, except it comes from a local
        font file, and it's not working.
      </FromLocal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For some reason, the text in `FromGoogle` uses the Google font fine, while the text from `FromLocal` doesn't. My first thought was that it's an issue with the path, but if it is, I couldn't tell.

Here's the [full project on GitHub](https://github.com/TrevLev/react-emotion-local-font). I used Create React App, and removed all the irrelevant boilerplate.

Comment: I'm facing exactly same issue. Have you found the solution, please?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't. It may be worth your time to look at [this gatsby plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader/), which does have a module for custom fonts. However, I have failed to get that to work successfully. Also, [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is now able to generate static websites just as Gatsby does. If you're willing to try migrating, maybe see if this issue persists using a different static site generator.

Answer (score 3):

In my Next.js app I am using emotion with these versions:

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.1.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
```

My global styles are:

```
export const GlobalStyles = () => (
    <Global
        styles={css`
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Faustina';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 700;
                src: local(''), 
                    url('/fonts/Faustina/Faustina.woff') format('woff'),
                    url('/fonts/Faustina/Faustina.ttf') format('truetype');
            }

            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-family: Faustina;
            }

            html,
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        `}
    />
);
```

My fonts are in

```
project_root/public/fonts/Faustina

// explicitly
project_root/public/fonts/Faustina/Faustina-Bold.ttf
project_root/public/fonts/Faustina/Faustina-Bold.woff
```

In order to see font changes, I needed to restart dev server, e.g. `yarn dev`. Before restarting I had same issue where fonts weren't displayed (even downloaded in dev tools Network tab).

Answer (score 1):

am using these versions in my gatsby project;

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
 "gatsby": "^4.8.0"
```

index.html file is not available so you can't add `<style>` html tag and embed @font-face inside it.

Host your downloaded fonts inside your src/myfonts directory then import any of your fonts using the static import statement.

```
import font1 from './myfonts/font1.ttf';
```

then call `url(font1)` css function with the font1

```
const globalStyle =  css`
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'font1';
      src: url(${font1}) format('truetype');
    };
`;
```

it worked in my case;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250870/9423578).

I needed to define the fonts in a css file that is imported into the `index.html` like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/fonts.css" />
```

I was then able to reference the font family names in my emotion theme and have them load correctly.