# parcel/typescript/fonts - How to load a font and use in HTML canvas

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

Noob here ;(

I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279163/how-to-load-font-from-font-face-with-parcel) to successfully load and use my font on my HTML page.

I now want to use this font when drawing to a canvas.

My css..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url("/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}

body {
    font-family: 'myfont';
}
```

But when I try to use it in my typescript...

```
draw(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    context.font = 'myfont';
    context.fillText('Hello covid world', 50, 60);
}
```

...it uses the default font. I tried changing `context.font = 'myfont';` to `arial` to check the font changed. It did.

So how do I use my custom font in a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this really helpful page](https://blog.harveydelaney.com/creating-a-game-using-html5-canvas-typescript-and-webpack/) which uses this to load the css...

```
declare var require: any;
require('../css/main.css');
```

It doesn't appear to wait for the font to be loaded as the first time it renders the text it still uses default font. However, it does eventually load the font which is progress!

However however, I do have a image manager class that waits for images to load so I'll just add the font file in there.